# Use Qt Quick Controls 2 UIs in Qt Installer Framework

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols, qt-installer

I want to make a `Qt Quick Controls 2`-based installer. Doing so from scratch will take several hours from my time, so I want to use the Qt Installer Framework. It's possible?

So far I have customized wizard pages using style sheets, and even replace some pages with custom ones, but they are `QWidget`-based pages, and I need `Qt Quick Controls 2`-based pages.